# How to avoid Singleton/Statics/Injection in my puzzle game

Tags: java, game-design, swing

I am developing a puzzle game in java with swing.
Purpose of the game to find the  all the correct pairs on the board without ur lifes reaching 0 , preety simple etc.

1. I have a class *My_Button* which extends *JButton*.
2. My game consists of 6 type of Tiles (*square* , *circle* etc)
3. All these type of tiles extend *My_Button* class and i*mplements my_Actions* interf.
4. *my_actions* interface has some methods, not crucial for the question.
5. I have *my_board* class which holds arraylist with buttons , initializes buttons, fills the array , checks for validity between pairs , delete pairs etc.
   It contains all the game functions in a way.

Now my main problem is the *actionListener* implementation and logic.
In my ActionListener in simple words i add the button that got clicked to a temp array and when 2 buttons got added to this array i do certain actions.
for example: (pseudo)

```
ActionListener{
my_board.posible_pair.add(this); 
my_board.click_counter++;
my_board.check_game_state();
}
```

**!check_game_state() runs if's and updates all the info of the game like: tries,score,check_valid_pair,delete etc.!**

Now my thinking and my  question laid out:

**First case:** 
If i make every Tile class implement actionListener like the example above ill have to make my_board singleton to be able to have acess to all this variables outside of the my_board class.

**Second case:** 
even if i implement actionListener inside the my_board class and add the actionlistener through anonymous classes to my button after i add them to the board it gives error ofc because the scope gets weird.

**Third case:** 
full static class and variables, its really bad programming so id like to avoid.

**QUESTION:**

--How i can reconstruct my project to manage these problem without singletons/static ?

--How i can avoid putting the check_game_state() inside the ActionListener which also is a bad practice?

I checked infinite number of qestions on this forum , google , stackoverflow but nothing really helps on the specifics. 
I have developed simmilar games before but i always follow the singleton tecqniques and id like to change that.

Comment: Is the ActionListener receiving communication from the buttons via direct reference eg: `button1.actionListenerReference.addPair(this)`? And you are trying to decrease this tight coupling without using singletons or statics? If I am understanding correctly I think the architectural approach I would recommend is using a pub/sub event driven system. You will be able to communicate via events between the button and action listener without tight coupling. Let me know if I'm understanding correctly or if I have made some misinterpretations/wrong assumptions.

Answer (score 1):

i would suggest that you do some work on your design - it is **a very good** idea to rethink your design to make better (less bugs)  , better to test & maintain and even adding new features.

### refactoring into dynamic context

You can move your whole static code into a dynamic context once you start your `static main` method

```
public class Game {

    //static context
    public static void main(String[] args){
        Game myGame = new Game();
        game.executeDynamicMethod();
    }

    //dynamic context
    public void executeDynamicMethod(){
    }

}
```

### planning tools

furthermore make a plan what entities should be in your game and what relations they have. Best practice for these plans is usually to use UML diagrams

[image]

Use this (or a better suitable) Model to create your classes.

### Design hints

Lastly you should try to seperate concerns. Most likely you have a game entity, a so called game model and a GUI to display that game. keep these two things separate as far as you can!